# How can I have filtered/seach results page stay place be remembered whilst navigating back and fourth to it using 'mysite.com/?search=words' concept?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I click the 'back' button or the 'refresh/reload' button or the 'forward' button in the browser my search/filtered results disappear. How can I have the results page stay with the keyword whilst navigating back and fourth to the page, or refreshing/reloading using mysite.com/?search=words concept?

JS

```
<body>
<script>
var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

markInstance = new Mark(table);
if(document.getElementById('myInput').value.length >0){
ContactsearchFX();
}
input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});


function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {
    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}

function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
    exclude: ['.nonsearch']
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');              $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +             '"</p>'); 
}



/* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
/* on form submit find the trigger */
if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0 ){
    /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
});    
/* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */
```

////

CSS

```
<style>
.input-wrap  {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}


.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}



#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
background: orange;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
mark {
background: initial;
}    .style1  {
text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">
<label>
Search 
<input id="myInput" type="text" spellcheck="false"
   placeholder="Search Titles"/>
<div class="hintsWrap">
<p id="noMatches"></p>
<p class="hints">
Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
</p>
</div>
</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />
```

Have been trying to integrate this piece of JS with not too much success

```
let input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
text = '';

// Keyup listener on input field
input.on('keyup', function(e) {
 text = input.value;

  // Add the text change to the browser history so users can go          back/forward,         and save url parameter in the history state
 let historyState = {
'text': text,
}
window.history.pushState(historyState, null, `?search=${text}`);
});


// Run something after History listener finds search text exists
const updateSearch = function(text) {
console.log(`I found the search to be: ${text}`);
}

// History listener
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
let state = e.originalEvent.state

 if (state !== null) { //If text exists
 updateSearch(state.text)
 } else { //If no text set (URL has no params)
console.log('no history state found')
 }
});
```

Comment: I didn't read your code, but you could write the user's search query to local storage and then populate that field with that string every time you load that page.

Comment: Please some code

Comment: No. I gave you plenty of keywords to get google results that tell you everything you need to know. Do some research and then try writing some of the code yourself. If you get stuck on something specific in your code, report back.

Comment: Please some demo code to get me started

Comment: @Orbit SO is not a code on demand page. People here try to answer your questions and help you when you get stuck, but they don't have to write your code or examples you can start with. they usually are paid to do so on their jobs.

Comment: I'm stuck figuring out how to have 'push' to browsers history or sessionState

Comment: You must Save your data somewhere and on page load retrive them. Session is good option.

Comment: I don't know how save to url e.g my-site.com/?search=words'

Comment: @weltschmerz - Please look at the 4th piece of code in this question - may make sense to you

Answer (score 0):

You could either save `search` parameter in your local storage (or session storage) or you could keep it in your `GET` at all times.

```
let searchQuery = $(`#id`).val();
// based on either a click or blur event fire
let nQuery= retrieveItems(`interests`, `search`); //this is your GET query string which you assign to your URL
let searchArr = localStorage.getItem(`interests`); // retrieve the original array as an array
searchArr.push(searchQuery); // push the new value into the array
localStorage.setItem(`interests`, searchArr); // override the object property
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Now, every time you "search" for something, it'll push it in your local storage (or again, you could make it a session storage). You can now either loop through the `interests` property and assign it to your `href` such as:

```
function retrieveItems(name, getName)
{
    let searchqueries = localStorage.getItem('interests');
    let urlParam = getName;
    if (searchqueries.length > 0)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < searchqueries .length; i++)
        {
            //keep in mind you need to insert a character or whatnot to be able to "break" the words the user looked up for.
            urlParam += searchqueries[i];
        }
        return urlParam; //assign this to your 
    }
    return [];
}
```

Now call the function, bind the return value to a variable and then assign that to your `href`.

Notice: I did not test this, so it could contain errors, or it will need some modification. Also, it could probably be done in a much neater way, but this is an example to get you going.

Comment: @I try so hard but I cry harder - tested code, it does nothing unfortunately